# Active directory name change only propagates to DisplayName in TFS

Tags: tfs

A user of TFS had a typo in their name, and requested it be changed.  Our IT Department updated their Active Directory account, which now has the correct spelling.  This change propagated to DisplayName in tblIdentity, but not to ProviderDisplayName, (or AccountName, or DistinguishedName), so the user can still see the incorrect spelling on some fields in TFS.  How do we correct the spelling, or synchronize with the new A/D spelling?

We are using TFS 2017, Update 3.

Edit:
I ran this query to confirm that the synchronization job has run recently (many times after the A/D change last week):

```
USe tfs_Configuration
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM [Tfs_Configuration].[dbo].[tbl_JobHistory]
WHERE JobId='544DD581-F72A-45A9-8DE0-8CD3A5F29DFE'
```

Comment: How long has it been since the name was changed? AD synchronization isn't instant.

Comment: It was last week, and as mentioned, the DisplayName updated automatically, so I assume the sync job must have run.